# How to check the overall health of database using Toad?

Tags: toad

Anyone have any idea? And any open source sofware which also seens to perform this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The DBA version of Toad has such a feature. In my version, it is under the DBA menu, and is called "Health Check".
Screenshot http://toadsoft.com/get2know96/Web/

Answer (score 1):

From Quest Software: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02LmtxyRVJ8

In Toad 11,  Main Menu -> Database -> Diagnose -> DB Health Check. You can learn more about it [at ToadWorld](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/07/07/toad-database-health-check.aspx), though this may be for a newer version.